# Azure Synapse - How to Create a Synapse Lake Database / Serverless Database via Terraform or Azure CLI

Tags: terraform, azure-synapse, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cli

I am using Terraform scripts via Azure devOps Pipelines to create the underlying Azure Resources.

There is no a requirement to create a "Lake Database / Serverless Database" under Synapse.

I've had a look at the Terraform docs. but can't see any TF command that does this - I may well be missing something.

Is there a TF command to create a "Lake Database / Serverless Database" under Synapse ?

OR

Another method that can be automated - maybe an Azure CLI command(s) - again I could not find anything...?

Comment: Terraform is not supported and there is no CLI script to create serverless database or lake database.

Comment: Currently looking at the following....

resource "azapi_resource" "Registrar_Lake_Database" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_synapse_workspace.synapse]
  name       = "Registrar"
  parent_id  = azurerm_synapse_workspace.synapse.id
  type       = "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/kustoPools@2021-06-01-preview"
....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/18234), Terraform does not support creating serverless databases or lake databases, and there is no CLI script available for this purpose. You can create a serverless SQL database using the SQL script below:

```
CREATE DATABASE db
```

This script will create a serverless SQL database successfully, as shown below:

[image]

Creating a lake database manually is the only option, as demonstrated below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Synapse - the below creates a serverless-database on the serverless endpoint:

```
resource "null_resource" "synapse_create_db" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<EOT
az login --service-principal -u ${var.deploymentSpAzureDevOps_Sec} -p ${var.deploymentSpAzureDevOps_EA_Client_Id} --tenant ${var.tenant_id}
$accessToken = az account get-access-token --resource "https://database.windows.net/" | ConvertFrom-Json | select-object -ExpandProperty accessToken
$ServerInstance = '${var.sqlOnDemand}'
$Database = "master"
function SqlQuery($ServerInstance, $Database, $AccessToken, $query)
{
 $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerInstance;Database=$database;"
 $connection.AccessToken = $AccessToken
 $connection.Open()
 $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
 $command.CommandText = $query
 $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
 $table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
 $table.Load($result)
 $connection.Close()
 return $table
}
$SQLQuery = @"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '${local.databasename}')
  CREATE DATABASE [${local.databasename}];
"@
  SqlQuery -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -AccessToken $AccessToken -query $SQLQuery
EOT 
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
  triggers = {
    trigger_each_run = uuid()
  }
}
```